Simulate difference-in-difference process with correlated errors
I am trying to create a dgp for difference-in-difference estimation that requires clustering of standard errors in the estimation step for correct inference. I envision a process with two groups and two periods and each group is composed of a number of n_units.
I am having trouble to get the residuals to be correlated after estimating y_obs ~ time_period*treatment. I believe that is to due to group level fixed effect which "eat" up the within group correlation in the residuals. Is there a away to simulate a process s.t. this correlation is preserved even when having group fixed-effects in the regression?
library(dplyr)

make_data <- function(n_units = 1000, treatment_effect = 0, rho = 0) {
    n_periods <- 2
    is_treated <- sample(c("treated", "untreated"), n_units, 
                         replace = TRUE)

    data <- data.frame(
        unit_id = rep(seq(n_units), n_periods),
        treatment = relevel(as.factor(rep(is_treated, n_periods)), 
        ref = "untreated"),
        period = rep(1:2, each = n_units)
    ) |>
        mutate(alphai = rnorm(1, 
         mean = if_else(treatment == "treated", 2, 1)), .by = unit_id)
     |> mutate(eps_common = rnorm(1, 
       if_else(treatment == "treated", 2, 1), {{ rho }}), 
         .by = treatment) |>
        mutate(eps_individual = rnorm(n(), 0, 1)) |>
        mutate(
            y_obs = case_when(
                period == 1 ~ alphai + eps_common + eps_individual,
                period == 2 & treatment == "treated" ~ alphai + 
                 treatment_effect + eps_common + eps_individual,
                period == 2 & treatment == "untreated" ~ alphai + 
                     eps_common + eps_individual
            )
        ) |>
        arrange(unit_id, period)
    return(data)
}


